# iOS Unit Test Simulate Gestures

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests for iOS. Is there any way to simulate gestures like panning or zooming? I'd like to simulate those gestures on a view then verify the result.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an automation test framework for tests involving views, view controllers, and gestures. Examples would include [UIAutomation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html), [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF), or [Calabash](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios).

Answer (score 0):

You can use presenter pattern where you have a presenter for the controller and all controller does is on receiving the gesture, it asks presenter to do all the work it has to do. Then you can unittest the presenter.

Here is one simple example for presenter in swift for touchup on button

Controller:

```
Class myController: UiViewController, MyView {
    var presenter: MyPresenter!
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
            presenter.buttonPressed()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.presenter = MyPresenter(view: self) 
    }
}
```

Presenter:

```
Class MyPresenter {
    init(view: MyView) {
        self.myView = view
    }
    func buttonPressed() {
         //code to be tested
    }
}
```

Protocol:

```
protocol MyView {
    //methods for presenter to communicate with view controller
}
```